# jQuery slide html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I am making a basic `div` for a social navigation bar that runs vertical along the left side of the webpage.

I am trying to make each individual `div` slide right to a `width: 64px;` when you hover over it, and return to normal width when your mouse leaves it.

```
        <div class="social-buttons">
            <div class="social-btn"><b>f</b></div>
            <div class="social-btn"><b>G+</b></div>
            <div class="social-btn"><b>T</b></div>
            <div class="social-btn"><b>E+</b></div>
        </div><!-- end of social-buttons -->

.social-btn {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #206999;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
  .social-btn:hover {
width: 64px;
transition-property: width;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

  .social-btn {
transition-property: width;
transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add on hover element on CSS like this

```
.social-btn {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #206999;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.social-btn:hover {
 width: 64px;
}
```

[Here is Live Demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/mabdullah353/7m0fnwvt/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to animate the width using JQuery like this? https://jsfiddle.net/1nL9mq69/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".social-btn").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).animate({"width":"64px"}, 200);
    });

    $(".social-btn").on("mouseleave", function() {
         $(this).stop();
         $(this).animate({"width":"48px"}, 200);
    });

});
```

The `200` parameter controls how long, in milliseconds, the animation runs for, so you can change that to make it slide out more quickly or slowly.